# handling multi clicking and request processing

Tags: java

we have to share an API with the client that he will use besides his banner , anyone who clicks on the banner will be charged from our API , issue is if the user is clicking the banner multiple time say 5 times in a sec , how can this be handled in the Servlet , "singlethreadmodel" is deprecated is there any other way where i can prevent people getting charged multiple times because they are clicking banner back to back.

Comment: After clicking for the first time make the banner disabled

Comment: banner is third party with my api at the backend.